# Customize Material UI ToolTip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

I'm trying to customize material ui tooltip for react storybook

I have tried changing some css properties like width, height, background color but failed to see those changes

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createStyles, withStyles, Tooltip, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = (theme: any) => createStyles({
  tooptip: {
    width: "92px",
    height: "36px",
    borderRadius: "18px",
    boxShadow: "0 20px 80px 0",
    backgroundColor:"red"
  }

});
interface ToolTipProps {

  children?: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element;
  classes?: { [key:string]: string };

}
function ToolTip({ classes }: ToolTipProps): JSX.Element {

  return (
      <Tooltip title="Tooltip" classes={classes}>
        <div>Hover</div>
      </Tooltip>
  );
}
export default withStyles(styles)(ToolTip);
```

I need to customize tooltip

Answer (score 4):

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

const styles = {
    tooltip: {
        width: "92px",
        height: "36px",
        borderRadius: "18px",
        boxShadow: "0 20px 80px 0",
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }
};

const CustomTooltip = withStyles(styles)(Tooltip);

function MyCustomTooltip() {
    return (
        <CustomTooltip title="Tooltip">
             <Button>Custom Tooltip</Button>
        </CustomTooltip>
   );
}

export default MyCustomTooltip;
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pike-nn95i)

You have to do Typescript stuff by yourself. I don't use it, so I don't know how it should be done :).

Answer (score 4):

4 years and 2 months later, I only needed to customize the width.

In my case, this was the solution.

```
<Tooltip
    title={'Tooltip text'}
    componentsProps={{
        tooltip: {
            sx: {
                width: '6rem'
            },
        },
    }}>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: This solution appears to be useful in 2024, only using the MUI's componentsProps without styled and theme.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to customize material-ui components would be to use themes.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import lightGreen from "@material-ui/core/colors/lightGreen";
import lime from "@material-ui/core/colors/lime";
import teal from "@material-ui/core/colors/teal";
import yellow from "@material-ui/core/colors/yellow";
import deepOrange from "@material-ui/core/colors/deepOrange";

export default createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: lime,
    secondary: teal,
    error: deepOrange,
    action: {
      disabledBackground: teal[400]
    },
    text: {
      primary: lightGreen[900],
      secondary: teal[700],
      disabled: yellow[600]
    }
  },
  status: {
    danger: "orange"
  }
});
```

and then wrap your app / component implementation in material-ui `ThemeProvider`

```
import GardenTheme from './themes';
/* your story / component code */
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={GardenTheme}>
    /* tooltip */
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

I wrote a short article on usage of material-ui themes on medium [link](https://medium.com/@aleksander_37591/easily-switch-material-ui-themes-in-your-storybook-474638bfc3f1)

Comment: I wanted to apply the [html font-size](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#html-font-size) to the Tooltips title, too which wasn't successfull with ThemeProvider only. Wrapping the **title** param in a <Typography> tag then worked.

Answer (score 0):

similar to solution1 but with typescript type

```
const CustomWidthTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }: TooltipProps) => (
   <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
   ))({
      [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
            maxWidth: 500,
      },
   });
```

For detail, see https://refine.dev/blog/material-ui-tooltip-component/#width-variations